# create aws glue crawler with multiple s3 paths

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, aws-glue

I would like to create aws glue crawler with boto3 API as per the below documentation.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_crawler

Here I need to pass almost 100 s3 paths, I would like to create it programmatically.

```
response = client.create_crawler(
    Name='string',
    Role='string',
    DatabaseName='string',
    Description='string',
    Targets={
        'S3Targets': [
            {
                'Path': 'string',
                'Exclusions': [
                    'string',
                ],
                'ConnectionName': 'string'
            },
        ],
```

Here I need to pass 100 paths from s3 at a time to API call,Is there better approach to do it programmatically instead of adding all s3 paths manually to API call?

Comment: does these S3 paths follows a pattern ? and where are you planning to maintain the list of s3 paths?

Comment: yes, I have a pattern like below
s3://Bucketname/data/test/abc.parquet
s3://Bucketname/data/testone/def.parquet
How do we pass all the paths at a time ? Any idea ? I appreciate your response

Comment: Passing the full path is not a good idea to crawler . Are all these files under s3://Bucketname/data are of same schema ? Once the table is created what will you be using to read data from these tables?

Answer (score 1):

As Prabbakar mentioned, it is not best practice to pass the object full prefixes to the crawler. Consider adding the entire path and use exclusions. If that is on the only way, you can unroll the prefixes from a list in your Targets object

```py
s3_paths = [
    "s3://Bucketname/data/test1/",
    "s3://Bucketname/data/testone",
    "s3://Bucketname/data/testrandompath",
     ...
]
response = client.create_crawler(
    Name='string',
    Role='string',
    DatabaseName='string',
    Description='string',
    Targets={
        'S3Targets': [
            {
                'Path': s3_path,
                'Exclusions': [],
                'ConnectionName': 'string'
            }
            for s3_path in s3_paths
        ]
     }
)
```